# Copy Tuple OR save Id of Tuple in another table (ProductLogs) when any field is updated in a specific table (products)

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration

I don't know the solution I'm finding, will be possible or not.

**Problem Statement:** There is a table named **Products** in DB, I need to keep track of products with price updated/modified, but I don't want to use modified_date column because it doesn't exist.

A senior resource asked me to run a query in SQL server DB, whenever that table will be modified that record will be copied to your log/track table, so I can find from there.

Comment: [System versioned table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017) or [trigger](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4055/create-a-simple-sql-server-trigger-to-build-an-audit-trail/)

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4055/create-a-simple-sql-server-trigger-to-build-an-audit-trail/ this link helped me understand what triggers are and how  have to write one, Thanks, you saved my day,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use trigger after `UPDATE`:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER ModDate
    ON YourTable
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN        
    INSERT INTO dbo.LogTable(DateModified)
    VALUES (GETDATE());
    PRINT 'New Block Date Added';
END
```

**UPDATE:**

When trigger works, under the hood there are two tables:

- "INSERTED"
- "DELETED"

The data in these virtual tables  depends what you are doing:

- Insert operation: when you insert a record, virtual table "inserted" contains the newly inserted record ,where "DELETED" virtual table remains empty
- Update operation: when you update a record, at first the old record will be placed into the "DELETED" virtual table and the newly updated record is hold by the "INSERTED" virtual table.

  That means you can get the old value from "DELETED" and the currently updating value through "INSERTED" virtual table. you can query them like:

  ```
  -- To get the old record value
  SELECT * FROM DELETED

  -- To get the updated value
  SELECT * FROM INSERTED
  ```
- Delete Operation: When try to delete any particular record the deleted record will be inserted into the "DELETED"  virtual table.

So your trigger should look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ModDate
    ON YourTable
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN        
    INSERT INTO dbo.LogTable(DateModified, IdUpdatedRow)
    SELECT GETDATE(), INSERTED.YourIdOfUpdatedRow;
    PRINT 'New Block Date Added';
END
```

Comment: Thanks, man, this one is storing a date when any tuple will be modified, but I need to keep track which tuple modified, I need to store that tuple in LogTable

Comment: @User6007962 please, see an updated section of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by StepUp, the classical way to do this is to use an AFTER TRIGGER. The example solution will only be trigger with UPDATEs. In your case, you would want to also add triggers for INSERT and DELETE, or adapt that one trigger to handle those 3 event types.

Note that the use of a trigger can affect the @@ROWCOUNT, so may affect functionality.

Because of that, I think recent versions of SQL Server have alternative mechanisms.